# flavor splitting of quark masses

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks

It seems pretty clear that flavor symmetry splits the quark masses.  It seems extremely odd that a global gauge symmetry of the Standard Model fields could or would produce such extreme splitting as is calculated in the typical models and confirmed in experiment.  The range seems more suited to the magnitude of the color force itself, and yet the color force is flavor agnostic.  Does this bother anyone else?   Perhaps it's neatly explained somewhere that I've missed?

Comment: There is no flavour symmetry in the Standard Model, and  quark masses are parameters of the Standard Model, see for instance page $14$ of this [paper](http://hep.tsinghua.edu.cn/~gaoyn/SM_tests/Lecture1.pdf).

Comment: I think you have it backwards. The splitting is not calculated as numbers, the numbers come from a fit to experiment. Have a look at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/quark.html . Yes, the masses are flavor dependent and it it the higgs field that gives them the mass. The Higgs boson itself is fairly heavy so I cannot see what is bothering you.

Comment: That's the point: *if* there were a global flavor symmetry, it would be badly broken. Unless you find a good rule (not a numerological Koide formula, that is) explaining fermion masses, you have no right to claim there *should* be one, anymore than you'd expect a theory for the mass splitting of planets or their satellites, or the lengths of rivers.

Comment: I agree totally about the fermions masses.  There's a good chance they're random unless/until someone comes up with a compelling theory otherwise.